# Java client to authenticate against CAS server

Tags: java, cas, resttemplate

I have written a client app with java by following:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/restful+api

I was able to get TGT and service ticket. I am also able to "validate" the service ticket against CAS through my app i.e. against:

```
https://<HOST>:8443/cas/serviceValidate
```

Using that service ticket, I am able to verify that it works from browser:

```
https://<HOST>:8443/MyProject/login/cas?ticket=<TICKET_ID_FROM_MY_CLIENT_APP>&service=<ENCODED URL OF SERVICE>
```

works

But that service ticket does not work from my app.
I even tried:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> s1 = rt.getForEntity("https://<HOST>:8443/MyProject/login/cas?ticket=<TICKET_ID_FROM_MY_CLIENT_APP>&service=<ENCODED URL OF SERVICE>", String.class);
```

The response is default login page from CAS. But when trying on browser again, it works. Note, I am using identical url for both testing in browser and my app.

(I have modified CAS config to extend life of TGT and service tickets for 1 hour and validity count till 1000, so I know expiration is not the problem.)

What is the problem? Does this have to do with cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was RestTemplate is stateless. So, I used: 
StatefullRestTemplate from https://github.com/folkengine/StatefulRestClient.git